# Google Sheets duration format does wrap around 24

Tags: google-sheets, formulas, google-sheets-dates, text-formatting

If I format the cells of a sheet to duration, it wraps around 24h
So adding those three cells (which should represent `HH:MM`):

```
05:00
18:00
02:00
```

with `SUM`, the result is `01:00` where I need the result `25:00`.

Comment: Cannot reproduce. I get the SUM of 25:00. If I format the sum to 'Time' then I get 01:00, but you haven't done that, right?

Comment: Try changing the format to _duration_.

Answer (score 2):

- all you need is format it like:

  ```
  =TEXT(SUM(A1:A3), "[hh]:mm")
  ```

  [image: 0]

Answer (score 1):

By default when you use `HH:MM` it's a `TIME` type of format

Example :
Format is `TIME` :

```
01:00:00
```

Format is `DURATION` :

```
25:00:00
```

Test :
`01/01/2019` + `25:00:00` = `02/01/2019 01:00:00` with the `TIME` format.

`01/01/2019` + `25:00:00` = `1043209:00:00` when using the `DURATION` format.

Conclusion : try using HH:MM:SS to avoid futur format problems with `DURATION` instead of `TIME`

[image: pic of format]